# Wall.post в вконтакте через сайт или standalone

Tags: vkontakte-api

В проекте нужно использовать постинг на стену сообщества через сайт.

Как это можно реализовать?

При авторизации приложения параметр `scope=wall` игнорируется.

Comment: При авторизации standalone-приложения он не игнорируется.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вы пытаетесь сделать это через rest api. Но отправить пост с сайта можно только через open api при этом при вызове wall.post будет открываться окно подтверждения выполнения действия (https://vk.com/dev/api_confirm). Сделать это "по тихому" как в standalone-приложении, через rest api невозможно, ввиду ограничений накладываемых вконтактом. Т.е. если авторизации по средствам OAuth выполняется непосредственно с сайта а не из standalon-приложения вконтакт это усекает и выдает acess_token с которым нельзя выполнять wall.post.